# Feasibility of non-self-intersecting path according to array constraints

Tags: c, algorithm

I have two arrays, each containing a different ordering of the same set of integers. Each integer is a label for a point in which two closed paths intersect in the plane. The two arrays are interpreted as giving the circular ordering (in clockwise order) of points along each of two closed paths in the plane, with no particular starting point. The two paths intersect with each other as many times as there are points in the arrays, but a path may not self-intersect at all. How do I determine, from these two arrays, whether it is possible to draw the two paths in the plane without self-crossings? (The integer labels have no inherent meaning.)

Example 1: A = {3,4,2,1,10,7} and B = {1,2,4,10,7,3}: it is possible

Example 2: A = {2,3,0,10,8,11} and B = {10,2,3,8,11,0}: it is not possible.

Try it by drawing a circle, with 6 points labelled around it according to A, then attempt to connect the 6 points in a second closed path, according to the ordering in B, without crossing the new line you are drawing. (I believe it makes no difference to the possibility/impossibility of drawing the line whether you start by exiting or entering the first loop.) You will be able to do it for example 1, but not for example 2.

I am currently using a very elaborate method where I look at adjacent pairs in one array, e.g. in Example 1, array A is divided into {3,4}, {2,1}, {10,7}, then I find the groupings in the array B as partitioned by the two members listed in each case:

```
{3,4} --> {{1,2}, {10,7}}
{2,1} --> {{4,10,7,3}, {}}
{10,7} --> {{3,1,2,4}, {}}
```

and check that each pair on the left-hand-side finds itself in the same grouping of the right-hand-side partition in each of the other 2 rows. Then I do the same, offset by one position:

```
{4,2} --> {{10,7,3,1}, {}}
{1,10} --> {{2,4}, {7,3}}
{7,3} --> {{1,2,4,10}, {}}
```

Everything checks out here.

In Example 2, though, the method shows that it is impossible to draw the path. Among the "offset by 1" pairs from array A we find {10,8} causes a partition of array B into {{2,3}, {11,0}}. But we need 11 and 2 to be in the same grouping, as they are the next pair of points in array A.

This idea is unwieldy, and my implementation is even more unwieldy. I'm not even 100% convinced it always works. Could anyone suggest an algorithm for deciding? Target language is C, if that matters.

EDIT: I've added an illustration here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODI0T.jpg. Here the paths to be reconciled share points 0, 1, 2 and 3. On the black path they are visited in order (A = {0,1,2,3}). On the blue path we have B = {0,2,1,3}. You can see on the left-hand side that this is impossible--the blue path will have to self-intersect in order to do it (or have additional intersections with the black path, which is also not allowed).

On the right-hand side is an illustration of the same problem interpreted as a graph with edges, responding to the suggestion that the problem boils down to a check for planarity. Well, as you can see, it's quite possible to form a planar graph from this collection of edges, but we cannot read the graph as two closed paths with n intersections--the blue path has "intersections" with the other path that don't actually cross. The paths are required to cross from inside to outside or vice-versa at each node, they cannot simply kiss and turn back.

I hope this clarifies the problem and I apologise for any lack of clarity the first time around.

By the way introducing coordinates would be a complete red herring: any point can be given any coordinates, and the problem remains the same. In a sense it is topological more than geometrical. Thanks for any additional suggestions on how to accomplish this feasibility check.

SECOND EDIT to show my current code. Like in the suggestion below by svinja, I first reduced the two arrays to a permutation of 0..2n-1. The input to the function is two arrays (which contain different orderings of the same 2n integers) and the length of these arrays. I am a hobbyist with no training in programming so I expect you will find several infelicities in the approach to coding. The idea is to return 1 if the arrays A and B are in a permutational relationship that allows the path to be drawn, and 0 if not.

```
int isGoodPerm(int A[], int B[], int len)
{
        int i,j,a,b;
        int P[max_len];   

        for (i=0; i<len; i++)
                for (j=0; j<len; j++)
                        if (B[j] == A[i])
                                {
                                P[i] = j;
                                break;
                                }

        for (i=0; i<len; i++)
                {
                if (P[i] < P[(i+1)%len])
                        {
                        a = P[i];
                        b = P[(i+1)%len];
                        }
                else
                        {
                        a = P[(i+1)%len];
                        b = P[i];
                        }
                for (j=i+2; j<i+len; j+=2)
                     if ((P[j%len] > a && P[j%len] < b) != (P[(j+1)%len] > a && P[(j+1)%len] < b))
                                return 0;
                }

        return 1;               
}
```

I'm actually still testing another part of this project, and have only tested this part in isolation. I tweaked a couple of things when pasting it into the larger codebase and have copied that version--I hope I didn't introduce any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the long question is hiding the true intent. I might be missing something, but it looks like the only thing you *really* need to check is if the points in an array can be drawn without self-intersecting. I'm assuming you can map the integers to the actual coordinates. If so, you might find the solution posed by the related math.statckexchange site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection) describing either the determinant-based method or the Bentley-Ottman algorithm for crossings to be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I have no information about the coordinates of the points, nor is any available or relevant. It's an entirely abstract problem I've encountered while working on something else. The answer as to the feasibility of constructing the drawing doesn't depend at all on the shapes of the paths or the locations of the points on them. It's a little like graph theory in that respect.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It actually is *very* relevant to have the coordinates of the points - primarily because it indicates whether or not you can move them about. If you have the freedom to move them about, then yes you want something like @svinja's planarity testing. Otherwise if the points have a value (even if unknown) then the problem is not the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct, but as nobody is posting an answer, here it is:

We can convert any instance of this problem to one where the first path is `(0, 1, 2, ... N)`. In your example 2, this would be `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `(3, 0, 1, 4, 5, 2)`. I only mention this because I do this conversion in my code to simplify further code.

Now, imagine the first path are points on a circle. I think we can assume this without loss of generality.  I also assume we can start the second path either inside or outside of the circle, if one works the other should, too. If I am wrong about either, the algorithm is certainly wrong.

So we always start by connecting the first and second point of the second path on the, let's say, outside. If we connect 2 points X and Y *which are not right next to each other on the circle*, we divide the remaining points into group A - the ones from X to Y clockwise, and group B - the ones from Y to X clockwise. Now we remember that points from group A can no longer be connected to points from group B *on the outside part*.

After this, we continue connecting the second and third point of the second path, but we are now on the inside. So we check "can we connect X and Y on the inside?" if we can't, we return `false`. If we can, we again find groups A and B and remember that none of them can be connected to each other, but now on the *inside*.

Now we're back on the outside, and we connect the third and fourth point of the second path... And so on.

Here is an image that shows how it works, for your examples 1 and 2:
[image]

And here is the code (in C#, but should be easy to translate):

```
    static bool Check(List<int> path1, List<int> path2)
    {
        // Translate into a problem where the first path is (0, 1, 2, ... N}
        var path = new List<int>();
        foreach (var path2Element in path2)
            path.Add(path1.IndexOf(path2Element));

        var N = path.Count;
        var blocked = new bool[N, N, 2];
        var subspace = 0;
        var currentElementIndex = 0;
        var nextElementIndex = 1;
        for (int step = 1; step <= N; step++)
        {
            var currentElement = path[currentElementIndex];
            var nextElement = path[nextElementIndex];

            // If we're blocked before finishing, return false
            if (blocked[currentElement, nextElement, subspace])
                return false;

            // Mark appropriate pairs as blocked
            for (int i = (currentElement + 1) % N; i != nextElement; i = (i + 1) % N)
                for (int j = (nextElement + 1) % N; j != currentElement; j = (j + 1) % N)
                    blocked[i, j, subspace] = blocked[j, i, subspace] = true;

            // Move to the next edge
            currentElementIndex = (currentElementIndex + 1) % N;
            nextElementIndex = (nextElementIndex + 1) % N;
            // Outside -> Inside, or Inside -> Outside
            subspace = (2 - subspace) / 2;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Old answer:

<strike>I am not sure I understood this problem correctly, but if I have, I think this can be reduced to [planarity testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing). I will use your example 2 for the numbers:</strike>

1. Create graph G1 from the first array; it has edges `2-3, 3-0, 10-8, 8-11, 11-2`
2. Create graph G2 from the second array; `10-2, 2-3, 3-8, 8-11, 11-0, 0-10`
3. Create graph G whose set of edges is the union of the sets of edges of G1 and G2: `2-3, 3-0, 10-8, 8-11, 11-2, 10-2, 3-8, 11-0, 0-10`
4. Check if G is planar.

This is if I correctly interpreted the question in the sense that the second path must not cross itself but must not cross the first path either (except for the unavoidable 1 intersection per vertex due to shared vertices). If this is not the case, then Example 2 [does have solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkuEj.png) (note how the 11-2 and 8-10 edges are crossed by the second path).

Comment: Thanks for this--but it turns out checking for planarity in your sense is not quite the same problem. I made an illustration that I hope will explain why. It's here: http://imgur.com/TS8xDIk . I'll add a description to the original post instead of here (not enough characters allowed in a comment).

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I added a different solution. I am not sure it is correct, though.

Comment: Thank you svinja for this contribution! As I understand it, it implements (or reinvents) the method I described in the original post, which I think of as simulating the hand-drawn method. I'll post my current code in the original post for the sake of comparison. I'm sorry I have no mojo for upvoting your answer.

Comment: Our algorithms seem to always return the same result (on a million random samples) and your algorithm is better - it is faster and doesn't use additional N^2 space. For a 10000 long list, in C# your algorithm takes 200 ms and mine 600 ms, and for a 100000 long list mine goes out of memory. :) I would say that your algorithm is not "unwieldy" at all! The only question is how to check the correctness.

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing that speed comparison. Yes the code I posted had been streamlined quite a bit after I originally asked the question--I realised I didn't have to store the blocked portions anywhere. Since I essentially only use one array, (considering the other as if it's ordered 0, 1, 2... 2n), I can use the greater than and less than operators. And I was quite pleased with the fake exclusive OR in the final "if" statement.

Comment: I think whereas my version establishes each "block", then looks through the rest of the array to see if any other paths on the same side are blocked by it, your version checks each path segment one at a time, computing a separate array of blocked segments for each.

Mine could be further improved, I think, because it does unnecessary checks: once we have established that segment a does not block segment b, we shouldn't need to check that segment b does not block segment a.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Checking 1 path segment at a time would be ok, but instead of calculating "blocked", I should have simply, in each step, gone over all the remaining segments and checked if any of them are blocked by this one, instead of calculating "blocked" for O(N^2) potential connections most of which will not actually occur.